# VBA converts string "12.00" to 1200 instead of 12.00. This happens only on EU regional setting and not US settings

Tags: vba, regional-settings

I don't know why but the string in vba is "12.00" and when I conver to a double with

```
myDouble= CDbl(stringDouble)
```

or

```
myDouble = stringDouble
```

I cannot do anything.. any help? (I cannot change the regional settings to US on all pcs..)

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you already noted in your comments, this is a regional setting - as your system is using `,` as the decimal separator, the string gets converted to `1200`. The solution in this case is to convert it with `Val`:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim myDouble As Double
    Dim stringDouble As String
    stringDouble = "12.00"
    myDouble = Val(stringDouble)
End Sub
```

Comment: exactly what I needed! This works on both systems. I also had another bug over this that made me crazier, because it overrides the value with a wrong one..

Comment: Oh my god... Why does ,`Val()` work?

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely due to regional settings - decimal separator differs. E.g. in my locale it's `,` - that's why for string-to-number conversion I use such syntax:

```
x = "12.00"
DBLnum = CDbl(Replace(x, ".", ","))
```

Comment: Depending you your regional settings, this might also result in wrong results - e.g. if you deploy the code on an English setting "12,345.67" would be converted to 12.34567 with this formula. `Val(x)` should do the job better!

Comment: @PeterAlbert Nice suggestion Peter, `Val` is more universal one. I used the above for strict input. My +1 to your version.