# VBA changing scientific value format

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code and it works as intended. Except it's giving wrong and unusable results.

```
Sub OpenXLS1()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strXLS As String

    strFile = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    strXLS = "results.xls"
    Workbooks.Open strFile & "\" & strXLS
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Machine.xlsm").Sheets("Import").Range("A2")
    Range("A1330").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Machine.xlsm").Sheets("Import").Range("B4")
    Range("A2661").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Machine.xlsm").Sheets("Import").Range("C1")
    Range("A3989").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Machine.xlsm").Sheets("Import").Range("D2")
    Range("A5318").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Machine.xlsm").Sheets("Import").Range("E2")
    Range("A6647").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Machine.xlsm").Sheets("Import").Range("F2")
    Workbooks(strXLS).Close
End Sub
```

results.xls file has values in both General (i.e. `0,000145958`) and scientific format (i.e. `6,83E-05`). After running the script I get the following results:

`0,000145958` has become `0,000145958184` only it's formatted as text and I can't use it in further formulas.

`6,83E-05` has become `6,83E+03` and that's super uncool.

Big thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you're not using the same `Application.DecimalSeparator` for both source and destination files. Try to verify if numbers are separated by `,` but your system separates them by `.` (or viceversa).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA converts string “12.00” to 1200 instead of 12.00. This happens only on EU regional setting and not US settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979333/vba-converts-string-12-00-to-1200-instead-of-12-00-this-happens-only-on-eu-re/14979823#14979823).

Comment: @MatteoNNZ You solved it. Thanks!

Interestingly, when I was doing the copy and paste process manually, Excel demanded me to import numbers with `,` as the decimal separator. Now, with VBA, it was the other way around.