# Converting "text formated as string" using CDbl() fails

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this function to convert *"numbers formatted as strings"* to numbers.

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' **Occurence:**
' This function is used in multiple handlers.
'
' **Summary:**
' This function iterates over all the (a) rows & columns in the 1st table
' on the sheet. It checks non-empty values. If value is not formatted as
' to the table while *"numbers formated as text"* are converted to
' `Double` and added to the array. At the end this array is written back
' to the table while *"numbers formated as text"* are converted to `Double`.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public Function remove_numbers_formated_as_text(ByVal sh As Worksheet)

    Dim r As Range
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long '''' arr's rows
    Dim j As Long '''' arr's columns
    
    Dim s As String
    Dim b As Boolean
    
    Set r = sh.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
    arr = r.Formula2

    '''' Iterate over a whole row and then proceed to next column
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            If IsEmpty(arr(i, j)) = False Then
                
                '''' Check whether array mamber stores formula
                b = r(i, j).HasFormula
                If b = True Then GoTo A
                
                '''' If cell doesn't treat numbers as text and is a numeric value,
                '''' then this is definitely a measurement that somebody entered and
                '''' it is therefore converted to double.
                s = r(i, j).NumberFormat
                If IsNumeric(arr(i, j)) And s <> "@" Then
                    arr(i, j) = CDbl(arr(i, j))
                End If
            
            End If
A:
        Next
    Next

    r.Formula2 = arr
    
End Function
```

I thought that this works, but it does not. Original array stores everything as  `Variant/Strings`, e.g. `"0.544502556324005"` but after these values are modified by `CDbl()`, they become a `Variant/Double` but they loose decimal separator, becoming e.g. `544502556324005`. So data get's corrupted...

Why are decimal separators removed? Any idea how to solve this? Or if anyone has some idea on how to convert *"numbers formated as strings"* better...

Comment: Can u give an example of an unput string?

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak I don't understand your suggestion.

Comment: I can't get the whole purpose of your function and asked whether you can give an example of input string to see how it looks like

Comment: Or you may try using `CDbl(replace(arr(i, j),",","."))` in case you have different seprators

Comment: The solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979333/vba-converts-string-12-00-to-1200-instead-of-12-00-this-happens-only-on-eu-re

Comment: Some suggest using `Val()` instead of `CDbl()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Original array stores everything as Variant/Strings, e.g.
> "0.544502556324005" ...

If so, don't use `CDbl` but `Val` which operates independently of the local settings:

```vb
If IsNumeric(arr(i, j)) And s <> "@" Then
    arr(i, j) = Val(arr(i, j))
End If
```

Comment: This was the solution. `CDbl()` id s real testament to Microsoft's sloppiness.

Comment: _CDbl() id s real testament to Microsoft's sloppiness._ No, but it is intended for another context - where you convert _localised_ strings, for example as returned by `Format(SomeDecimalValue, "0.00")` where "." is not a dot but the localised decimal separator. `Val`, however, matches `Str` which always returns a dot as the decimal separator.